# On Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade from php 5.6 to php 7.0

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

On an intranet `Ubuntu 14.04` Server a PHP-Application is running by use of `Apache2` and `php5.6` (mod_php). I'm in the need to upgrade to `php7.0`. (*I know both Trusty and PHP7.0 are outdated*).

I've tried my luck with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm
```

Unfortunately, both packages are not found anymore. Looking at https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?field.series_filter= I see there is no package for Trusty (*Which I totally understand but what causes me some trouble*).

1. Is it possible to use the packages from Xenial for Trusty?
2. If not is there some archive ppa which still has both packages?
3. What else can I do? (*Upgrading to bionic is, unfortunately, no option*)

Comment: This might be one of the cases where you want to separate the yet-to-fix legacy software from the software ready to deploy on bionic right now. A separate (virtual/container) machine that runs a recent php release, and removing php from the legacy stack.